# Oracle Materialized View. Build Deferred clause

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I created my materialized view with the BUILD DEFERRED clause

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mcastfilm 
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH FORCE ON COMMIT
AS SELECT ms.name moviename,r.role,a.first_name, a.last_name FROM moviesmall ms, role r , actor a 
WHERE ms.ID = r.movie_id
 AND r.actor_id = a.id
```

It is empty for now. As I read from Oracle Documentation:

> DEFERRED  Specify DEFERRED to indicate that the materialized view is
> to be populated by the next REFRESH operation. The first (deferred)
> refresh must always be a complete refresh. Until then, the
> materialized view has a staleness value of UNUSABLE, so it cannot be
> used for query rewrite.

.. what I expect is the view to be populated at my first insert over one table:

```
insert into moviesmall VALUES (400001,'My movie',2050,null);
commit;
```

However, my view is still empty. I had to execute :

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('mcastfilm');
```

.. to get my view updated.

My question is, what Oracle means with "The first (deferred) refresh must always be a complete refresh"?. As I understand, the "refresh" is specified by the clause "REFRESH FORCE ON COMMIT", so I expected my view to be updated when I commit one table.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand what documentation says, it is exactly what you did:

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('mcastfilm');
```

That's

> The first (deferred) refresh must always be a complete refresh